# How to add new value in model taken from form in angular

Tags: angular

I want to store data into `model.ts` using form values.

My `recipe.component.html` is:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Recipe Name</label>
  <input maxlength="50" class="form-control" name="recipeName" type="text" id="name" [(ngModel)]="recipeName">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <input maxlength="50" class="form-control" name="recipeDesc" type="text" id="description" [(ngModel)]="recipeDesc">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="imgPath" >Upload Image</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="recipeImg" type="url" id="imgPath" [(ngModel)]="recipeImg">
</div>
```

My `recipe.component.ts` is:

```js
recipe: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe(this.recipeName, this.recipeDesc, this.recipeImg),
];
```

My `.model.ts` is:

```js
constructor(name: string, desc: string, imagePath: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
    this.imgPath = imagePath;
}
```

I want to upgrade my model values every time I entered a value in input field

Comment: Why is recipe a array here? and not just : `recipe: Recipe = new Recipe(this.recipeName, this.recipeDesc, this.recipeImg);`

Comment: Because I want to store more than one recipes values entered by  user in the form

Comment: what is ur purpose for ?

Comment: I want to take values from user like recipe name, description and img and store it and display